# Deserialize subclasses without switch statements.

Tags: java, polymorphism

This is more of a software engineering question. 
I have a base class, and classes that extends a base class. My goal is to have a cleaner way to deserialize from, say a String. My current solution is to get this serialized string, extract the 'type' from a predetermined type field, and then use a switch statement to call the appropriate subclass' deserialization method. Is there any way to do this by leveraging the Java language rather than switch statements?

```
public abstract class Base {
   String type;
}

public class A extends Base{
   public A(String serializedString){...}
}

public class B extends Base{
   public B(String serializedString){...}
}

public class AuxMethods {

   public static Base deserialize(String s){
       String type = extractType(s); // gets the type from the serialized object string
       Base deserialized = null;
       switch(type){
           case "A":
              deserialized = new A(s);
              break;
           case "B":
              deserialized = new B(s);
       }

  }

}
```

Comment: Note that Java supports several automated serialization tools, such as Java object serialization and JAX-B. These may reduce your effort.

Comment: I'm aware. I'm using serialization tools, but I simplified for example purposes.

Comment: Okay. The tool you're using could determine the best solution. Might want to identify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the full class name (or assume that all classes are in a specific package), use Class.forName, and then look up the string constructor to create the object.

Comment: `Class.forName` do reflection. so I think he/she should avoid to use reflection unnecessary.

Comment: Could you explain 'look up the string constructor' ?

Comment: @BMT Reflection is exactly what you need here, though, so it's not "unnecessary".

Comment: @Realn0whereman Given a `Class<?> actual = Class.forName(type);`, the call `actual.newInstance()` would require a default constructor and is not what you want. You want to invoke the constructor taking a string, so you need to find that and call it, as in `actual.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(s)`

Comment: @SebastianRedl yeah it's one way to do it.there is no issue with it but it is better to write switch cases or conditional case if he has known no of classes.

Comment: @BMT I don't think I agree. A switch needs to be maintained when additional classes are added, reflection doesn't.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @SebastianRedl, but I would like to know why reflection is deemed so inherently bad? I also get the added bonus of more isolated tests that only have the potential to touch only relevant files.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I agree with you but for that you can add else condition which get instance of class with reflection. if you might forgot to mapping of it. I faced performance issue with it.

Comment: @BMT In that case not using reflection sounds like premature optimization to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're using serialization the correct way. You should simply serialize the `Base` object itself (using `ObjectOutputStream`) instead of storing the string class name of the sub-class object it points to. The actual object type would automatically get stored alongside the serialized sub-class object by Java.

This way when you deserialize (using `ObjectInputStream`) you automatically get the same sub-class object without using the `switch-case` statements to figure out which object the `Base` class reference should point to.

Comment: I'm using a proprietary serialization technology that can be thought of as json. I'll keep Object...Stream in my head for my own projects though.